# Is it possible to extract wallet_key (aes key) for encrypted master key from wallet.dat?

Tags: wallet.dat

According to this link(https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5331322.0), the initialized vector and aes key (wallet_key) can be derived by hashing the password with sha512, but can this wallet_key be extracted from wallet.dat(So,public info?)? Also, is this wallet_key the same as the value extracted with bitcoin2john.py?                                      hash512 = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password, salt, iterationcount) wallet_key = hash512[0:32] iv = hash512[32:48]

Answer (score 0):

> can this wallet_key be extracted from wallet.dat

No, to serve any purpose, an encryption key must be kept separate from the encrypted material.